# How to use datepicker for dynamically populated Rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm Working with Asp .Net MVC3 Following is the view page,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/CSS/jquery-ui.css")">  
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")"></script>  
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js")"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Reqrecdt").datepicker();
        $("#Docsreqdt").datepicker();
    });
</script>

@for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="ReqrecdDate" id="Reqrecdt" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="DocsreqDate" id="Docsreqdt" /></td>
    </tr>
}
```

While Running the Solution i'm getting Datepicker for first row textbox alone. what i need to change to get the datepicker on dynamic rows using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` must be unique, you need to use class instead:

```
@for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="ReqrecdDate" class="Reqrecdt" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="DocsreqDate" class="Docsreqdt" /></td>
    </tr>
}
```

then you can use `.` to target elements by class name:

```
$(function () {
    $(".Reqrecdt").datepicker();
    $(".Docsreqdt").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` attributes need to be unique within the page. With that in mind you need to use a `class` instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".Reqrecdt").datepicker();
        $(".Docsreqdt").datepicker();
    });
</script>

@for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="ReqrecdDate" class="Reqrecdt" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="DocsreqDate" class="Docsreqdt" /></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your resultant markup will have multiple elements with the same ID, therefore the first one is all that the script will hit.
Use a class class="Reqrecdt" and change your script to $(".Reqrecdt").datepicker();